# How to combine partitions in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have FreeBSD 8.3, two HDD drive.

1 HDD 
  /var partition 80GB
2 HDD
  /var partition 300Mb

How they can be combined into single /var partition like Linux LVM?

Comment: Are you sure that this is worth the effort (as in increasing from 80GB to 80,3GB)? Why not just copy the contents of the 300MB slice into the 80GB slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the existing contents of the two to appear together, you could use a union mount. This overlays one mountpoint on another and shows you the files from both. Updates/changes are recorded against the mounted filesystem, so you'd want to mount the 80GB partition onto the 300MB one. Check out the `union` option to mount (it's in the manpage).

If you want to combine the two into a 80.3GB usable partition (and reformat in the process) you could join the two together using `gconcat` which takes two (or more) partitions/disks and presents them as one disk. You'd then partition and mount this disk as `/var`. The `geom(8)` and `gconcat(8)` manpages are required reading if you're going to do this.